# Godot change_scene keep running last scene

Tags: godot

I'm a newbie, and I'm working on a game using Godot.

I'm making a game called "Pong", I'm creating a winning scene when one player reaches 5 points.

Here is my code:

```
if self.score1 >= winning_score or self.score2 >= winning_score:    
        get_tree().change_scene("res://compWin.tscn")
```

The code works in changing scene but after the scene is changed, the last scene which is the game still keep running. How can I fix it?

Comment: What do you have in autoloads? Autoloads survive scene changes/reloads.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to recreate this bug using your code, everything goes smoothly and the scene before compWin never ran in the background like you described. This error could be caused by other code.